# Do I risk anything by sending the windows installation id to the shop I bought it from?

Tags: windows-10, windows-activation

I bought a Windows 10 Pro key from a key-shop and had trouble activating Windows with it. It said that the key is already being used on another computer.

I called Microsoft but they couldn't help me and so I contacted the shop about it. They now want a screenshot of the window where the installation id is visible.

My question now is, if there are risks involved by sending this id to anyone. Like does this id show any private information about the PC it is installed on or could someone "steal" the windows copy with this id?

(I know that this is unlikely, considering I got the copy from the shop I'm going to send this id to in the first place, but I'm still interested in the answer)

Comment: What do you mean by "key-shop"? Can you tell us exactly where you bought the Windows 10 Pro from?

Comment: It's an online shop, which sells product keys for software. I had an uneasy fealing about this, but they are responsive with this issue, so it's something. Apparently, this key is from a company dissolution.

Comment: What was the name of the site though?

Comment: @DrZoo - Lets NOT give free promotion to a webiste that sold a used key to somebody shall we?

Comment: Can the installation ID be used for anyting notorious: Nope;  Of course if your being asked for an installation ID, that likely means you were sold a KMS license, which means its pratically useless to you since you obviously don't have a KMS server.

Comment: @Ramhound actually I wanted to look and see if others have had the same problem. If the asker posts the name of the website and sold him a used key, then someone has the audacity to buy a key from that site, that is completely on them.

Comment: @Bexo I suggest just using "slui.exe 4" which is the phone activation.  This will allow you to provide Microsoft the installation ID and in return get a confirmation id in return.  You can use the confirmation ID to activate your Windows installation.  The shop you are communicating with cannot help you activate Windows, only Microsoft can, unless they are willing to admit they sold you an invalid key.

Comment: @Ramhound: Thanks. Well, I already tried the phone activation and they told me this is a OEM license, which is also useless right now. I guess my question is answered and I'll see what they come up with next.

Comment: If its an OEM license then it can only be acticated on the OEM hardware it came with.  Since your talking about Windows 10, that means they sold you an invalid license, I strongly suggest you get your money back.  Unless you recieved OEM hardware with this key, the site you bought it from, basically sold you a bogus key.  OEM keys are a type of KMS license keys, so my original comment holds.

Comment: Well, they now send me the telephone confirmation Id (or whatever that is called), but without even entering it ... the Windows license was activated the next time I started the PC. I'm not sure how that worked, but work it did.